# view within panels? drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I have created a two column homepage with panels. I would like to use views to display the content within each col so to filter by date to publish. This project will be two blogs that will have fresh content every month. So I would like to use views to swap out the content on the first of every month. Is this possible and how do I do it? This seems to be getting complicated but I would think it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: You may have better luch asking this question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can display Views in Panels. but for that you need to enable **Views content panes** which is located at **/admin/modules/list** (in modules list) (see the screenshot below )

see the [screenshot here](http://img.freecircuits.org/images/views.png)

No if you add content in your panels there will be option for inserting Views.

Comment: Ok I got the view to display in the panel but its only showing a link not the actual content. Why is that. The view is a block. I also tried a page but I'm not getting the content I need. The input format is set to full html so it should show my full content.

Comment: The Block Views should be showing content for example see my website www.techiestuffs.com the front page is a panel and Each block is a view.Please post the screenshot if possible.